# When user click on like butten then show only like button

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4

```
   // LIke the page code    
     public function like($id){

        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $like_user = article_likes::where(
            ['user_id'=>$user_id,
            'article_id' => $id]
        )->first();

        if(empty($like_user->user_id)){
            $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $article_id = $id;

            $likes = new article_likes();
            $likes->user_id = $user_id;
            $likes->article_id = $article_id;
            $likes->save();
            return redirect()->back();
        }else{
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }

     // Dislike the page 
    public function dislike($id){
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $like_user = article_dislikes::where(
            ['user_id'=>$user_id,
            'article_id' => $id]
        )->first();

        if(empty($like_user->user_id)){
            $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $article_id = $id;

            $likes = new article_dislikes();
            $likes->user_id = $user_id;
            $likes->article_id = $article_id;
            $likes->save();
            return redirect()->back();
        }else{
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
```

**Blade page**

```
<div>
  <span class="">You think it is helpfull?</span>
  <a href="{{url('/likes/'.$articles->id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></a>
  <a href="{{url('/dislikes/'.$articles->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger  btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i></a>    
</div>
```

I want to achieve a scenario like this: When user likes the post by clicking on the like button, display only the like button, not the dislike button. Similarly, when a user clicked on dislike button, display the dislike button, not the like button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your controller looks like so this is what I'd do:

```
class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Article $article)
    {
        $dislike_user = article_dislikes::where(
            ['user_id'=>$user_id,
            'article_id' => $id]
        )->first();

        $like_user = article_likes::where(
            ['user_id'=>$user_id,
            'article_id' => $id]
        )->first();

        $rating = 0;
        if ($like_user !== null) {
            $rating = 1;
        }
        if ($dislike_user !== null) {
            $rating = -1;
        }
        return view('article', compact('article', 'rating'));
    }
}
```

```
<div>
  <span class="">You think it is helpfull?</span>
  @if($rating === 1)
    <a href="{{url('/likes/'.$articles->id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></a>
  @endif
  @if($rating === -1)
    <a href="{{url('/dislikes/'.$articles->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger  btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i></a>   
  @endif 
</div>
```